# Trim end of istream

Tags: c++, stream

Assuming I have a file looking like

```json
garbage (with no '{' nor '}')
garbage
{"json": "a very big json that may or may not span multiple lines"}
garbage
garbage
```

that I want to feed to a JSON deserializer that takes streams as input. Memory issues means I can't turn the whole file into a string to manipulate it.

I understand I should be able to do something like

```cpp
myIfstream.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '{');
myIfstream.unget();
```

to trim the useless lines at the start.

However, I can't find a way to trim the end of the stream/file without going through a string. How should I proceed?

Comment: Investigate whether whatever json library you're using provides an API that defines the string to be parsed using callback functions, then implement one that filters the input stream to the part you want. Alternatively, read this file, write out just the json part to another, temporary file, then use your json library to parse the contents of the temporary file.

Comment: Is it an option to read the file line by line and try to parse each line as JSON separately?

Comment: "Memory issues means I can't turn the whole file into a string to manipulate it". Your OS likely supports memory-mapped files, and then you can create a `std::string_view` of the JSON part.

Answer (score 0):

`std::getline` takes an optional delimiter; you can pass `}`. Of course, this will give you one "line" for each `}` inside your JSON; you'll have to append these parts yourself.

The last `std::getline(... , '}')` will fail with an EOF, or potentially with a `failbit` if there was more garbage than can be stored in a single string. Perhaps for good measure you could also catch `std::bad_alloc`.

This is a single-pass algorithm, so it's unavoidable that you're buffering trailing garbage. In a two-pass algorithm, you can find the beginning `{` and the final `}`, call `myIfstream.clear()` to reset the EOF state, seek to the first `{` and then read character by character until you get to the position of the final `}`.